# Eclipse won't recognise break points in included files

Tags: eclipse, cakephp, xdebug

I've been battling away for a month now getting xdebug working in eclipse to debug PHP applications. I've eventually managed to get xdebug working, hoorah!!!

Now what I've failed to get working for the last week or two is the break points. they work for the file I'm debugging, but they're not recognised when setting breakpoints within included files.

Has anyone had this problem before and know how to solve it? I've looked online for a solution  almost tirelessly without success.

I'm developing CakePHP applications, in case that's relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Nick

Comment: Are you using symlinks? What does the remote log file say when you make one? See http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log

Comment: I saw this thread as I was having the same problem. My solution may not be applicable, but in my case, I had acciedentally selected the wrong file (a different index.php) than the root. So it was breaking in that first file, but the paths were not the same so it could not step into any others.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into NetBeans. As an avid Eclipse user I found it to be superior when dealing with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in sublime text and solved it.

i looked into the xdebug log and noticed that at one point if was trying to reach my file at the wrong path.

To check if your problem is similar to mine, see if an exception makes your ide break.
Mine was breaking on exceptions like undefined variable (try echo $totoNotDefined)
But not on breakpoints

in the log look for something like that :
file:///

what i could see was :
file:///theFileBrowed.php

My problem was that the file was actually in d:/work/project/.../theFileBrowed.php

So i concluded that my xdebug config (in my ide : sublime text) must be wrong

indeed, i had this :

"path_mapping": {
        "/":"D://work/project/test"
    },

but apparently the D: was not loved

I changed it for :

"path_mapping": {
        **"/":"/D/work/project/test"**
    },

and it worked fine.

Sometimes if your path is in a folder with spaces or accentuations it can mess up the break points too.

I hope it helped